# UICollectionView reload data change order

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using UICollectionView, some cells contain animation on their view and when reloadData is triggered, the cells order is changed. How to resolve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: your code please, so that we can find root cause of issue.

Comment: So, it's a lot of code, i debug it a lot of time, so i will explain:
i have model object that is uploading to server and UICollectionViewCell with custom progress indicator. When model is uploaded, it's state is changed to upload, and simultaneously cell progress indicator start animation. As the state of model changed, reloadData was called(by NSFetchResultController delegate method) that cause the cells to change order and animation appear on the next cell.

Comment: Based on your explanation, it seems like the order of objects in model changes. Cross check if you are using any sorting. Try to print model object and check the order before and after.

Comment: Order of model is same, but order of cell(addresses) are changed